# DOMDocument PHP не верная кодировка

Tags: php, html, парсер

Делаю следующее:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
@$doc->loadHTMLFile("http://www.lg.com/ru/televisions/lg-42LB679V-lcd-led-televisions");
$div = $doc->getElementById('1342001880128')->nodeValue;
echo $div;
```

получаю:

```
Ð£Ð´Ð¾Ð±Ð½ÑÐµ 3D Ð¾ÑÐºÐ¸ ÐÐ·ÑÑÐ½ÑÐµ Ð¸ Ð½ÐµÐ´Ð¾ÑÐ¾Ð³Ð¸Ðµ Ð¾ÑÐºÐ¸ CINEMA 3D Ð½Ðµ Ð¸Ð¼ÐµÑÑ ÑÐ»ÐµÐ¼ÐµÐ½ÑÐ¾Ð² Ð¿Ð¸ÑÐ°Ð½Ð¸Ñ, ÑÑÐ¾ Ð´ÐµÐ»Ð°ÐµÑ Ð¸Ñ Ð
```

В чем проблема с кодировкой? Как исправить? Кодировка файла UTF-8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно решить проблему вот так:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$source = file_get_contents("http://www.lg.com/ru/televisions/lg-42LB679V-lcd-led-televisions");
$source = mb_convert_encoding($source, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'utf-8');
@$doc->loadHTML($source);
$div = $doc->getElementById('1342001880128')->nodeValue;
echo $div;
```

Comment: спасибо большое сработало!

Comment: теперь новая проблема: нужно вывести этот div в html со всеми вложенными тегами. echo $div->saveHTML(); вызывает ошибку Fatal error: Call to undefined method DOMElement::saveHTML()

Comment: получилось так: echo $doc->saveHTML($div);

Answer (score 0):

Возможно пригодиться, когда я столкнулся с подобной проблемой, мне помогла перекодировка в iso8859-1

echo iconv('utf-8','iso8859-1',$div);

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]